# How to populate page with data based on client-side date?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

This seems like it shouldn't be too difficult, but it's been evading me, so before I drive myself any crazier...

I need to populate a page in an ASP.net web application with data returned by a SQL stored procedure, one of whose arguments is Today's date.  This has to be the client-side date, of course, since the user may be in any time zone.  For the sake of users who might log in late at night, this date needs to be rechecked each time the page loads, in case the date has changed.

I have found lots of advice on line about passing data from the client to the server.  The difficulty for me has been the order of events:  How can I get the client-side date to the server BEFORE the page is rendered, so that it will display the data returned by the stored procedure?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: One option is to have the initial page *not* include the data, then have the client code immediately make an ajax request with the date as a parameter to get the appropriate data. (I notice you *did* include the "ajax" tag on your question, so presumably you already thought of this?) Another option would be to return two days' worth of data up front and have the client throw away whichever day's data doesn't apply.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I did not mention that I am revising an existing page that runs the stored procedure and populates the page with the data returned, all from the server side using vb.net.  The problem is that the parameter value it feeds to the proc is the server date, and it should be the client date.

Comment: Continuing my previous remarks:  Your suggestions seem workable, but I would rather not redesign the page so radically.  The solution I'm leaning toward is to create a separate html page that runs javascript on load to get the client date and save it to a text box in a form, then post it to the url of my existing page so that it can access the value.  That would require only minimal change to my old page.  What I still need to work out is how to make this new page run quickly and invisibly.  Thoughts?